# Memory issue when iterating over a list or arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory

I have a list of arrays such that:

```
arr = [array([1,2,3,4,5]), array([1,4,6,7]) .......]
```

which contains 40000 arrays. I would ideally like to have it as a 2d numpy array but I can't guarantee that all the arrays will be the same length.

I want to do something basic to all of the values in the list, such as:

```
out = (3*arr)+2
```

but I quickly run out of memory (on a 32GB machine) so its obviously very inefficient. I have tried iterating over the list and appending the results to a new list but this is equally inefficient.

Is there an efficient way to achieve this?

--------------- EDIT --------------

arr looks like:

```
[array([ 451.481649,  456.490319,  461.498989,  466.507659,  471.516329,
    476.524999,  481.533669,  486.542339,  491.551009,  496.559679,
    501.568349,  506.577019,  511.585689,  516.594359,  521.603029,
    526.611699,  531.62037 ,  536.62904 ,  541.63771 ,  546.64638 ,
    551.65505 ,  556.66372 ,  561.67239 ,  566.68106 ,  571.68973 ,
    576.6984  ,  581.70707 ,  586.71574 ,  591.72441 ,  596.73308 ,
    601.74175 ,  606.75042 ,  611.75909 ,  616.76776 ,  621.77643 ,
    626.7851  ,  631.79377 ,  636.80244 ,  641.811111,  646.819781,
    651.828451,  656.837121,  661.845791,  666.854461,  671.863131]),
array([ 451.481649,  456.490319,  461.498989,  466.507659,  471.516329,
    476.524999,  481.533669,  486.542339,  491.551009,  496.559679,
    501.568349,  506.577019,  511.585689,  516.594359,  521.603029,
    526.611699,  531.62037 ,  536.62904 ,  541.63771 ,  546.64638 ,
    551.65505 ,  556.66372 ,  561.67239 ,  566.68106 ,  571.68973 ,
    576.6984  ,  581.70707 ,  586.71574 ,  591.72441 ,  596.73308 ,
    601.74175 ,  606.75042 ,  611.75909 ,  616.76776 ,  621.77643 ,
    626.7851  ,  631.79377 ,  636.80244 ,  641.811111,  646.819781,
    651.828451,  656.837121,  661.845791,  666.854461,  671.863131]),
array([ 451.481649,  456.490319,  461.498989,  466.507659,  471.516329,
    476.524999,  481.533669,  486.542339,  491.551009,  496.559679,
    501.568349,  506.577019,  511.585689,  516.594359,  521.603029,
    526.611699,  531.62037 ,  536.62904 ,  541.63771 ,  546.64638 ,
    551.65505 ,  556.66372 ,  561.67239 ,  566.68106 ,  571.68973 ,
    576.6984  ,  581.70707 ,  586.71574 ,  591.72441 ,  596.73308 ,
    601.74175 ,  606.75042 ,  611.75909 ,  616.76776 ,  621.77643 ,
    626.7851  ,  631.79377 ,  636.80244 ,  641.811111,  646.819781,
    651.828451,  656.837121,  661.845791,  666.854461,  671.863131])]
```

Comment: Do you need to keep all of the values in memory at the same time? You might want to use generators to process the values lazily so that you can get rid of the parts of the data you don't need any more as soon as possible.

Comment: No I don't need them all in memory at the same time. Just each input array and output values at a time

Comment: How are you getting arr?  And what's the largest array within it? Seems strange to be running out of memory on a 32GB machine

Comment: I start with a simple 1d array (A) that has 432 values in it. I have two other arrays which have the shape (40000, 1), B and C. I want to use each value in B and C to slice A. something like: A[B:C]. As a slice only takes integers and not lists, I use a 'for' loop to iterate over the length of B, and append A[B[i]:C[i]] and append the result to arr. Hence each array in arr is subset of the original array I started with

Comment: If each slice is being processed independently of the others, you should skip building a big list with all the slices in it and just do the processing immediately on each slice after you create it (e.g. `for b, c in zip(B, C):out = 3*A[b:c]-2` -- presumably you'll do something more with `out` in the loop, but I don't know what).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are really doing it like you wrote, it is likely that you will run into memory issues, since

```
out = (3*arr)+2
```

replicates your array 3 times and then tries appending to it. Larger that constant, larger your array gets and hence the memory explosion.

To achieve what you want without memory issues, use

```
out = [[3*x + 2 for x in arr_list] for arr_list in arr]
```